# Monics and monomorphisms are the same as kernels in the additive category of R-modules.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

How can we show that in an additive category monics and monomorphisms are the same as kernels? 
Actually, I can show that a kernel is a monic and a monomorphism but I could not show that "a monic is a kernel" and "a monomorhism is a kernel in the additive category of R- modules".

Thank you for your help.

Claudia M.

Answer (score 5):

It's false in arbitrary additive categories (consider torsion-free abelian groups, here $2 : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ is monic and epic, but not iso, hence not a kernel), but it holds in the category of $R$-modules. Namely, if $U \subseteq V$ is a submodule, then it is the kernel of $V \twoheadrightarrow V/U$.